# No output node in World, Surface with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, world, output

With the Cycles engine, I get *No output node* in World Properties -> Surface:
[image: In my file]

This does not happen with the Evee engine. Also,
in a fresh Blender file, I see the expected content in Surface line even for Cycles:

[image: In a fresh file]

What has been lost in my file and how can I get the Surface content back?
Blender version is 3.4.1 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have deleted the *Output* by mistake, or you've set it to Eevee. Open the *Shader Editor*, switch it to *World*, make sure that the *World Output* is set to *All* and not only Eevee. If the *Output* doesn't exist press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Output > World Output*:

[image]

Comment: This helped instantly, thank you, @moonboots .